# Problem determining vocal range

Tags: voice, vocal-range

I am having trouble working out my vocal range. At first, my vocal instructor was convinced I was a tenor. However, I had to sing some songs in a lower range. Upon hearing me sing, he was surprised that I had the ability to sing so low, however difficult it was for me.

In my attempt to sing higher pitches, I sometimes use falsetto. While I know that falsetto isn't just an extension of my chest voice, sometimes I use falsetto in order to reach higher pitches.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Sing.  With regard to vocal practice, there is little point in not practising the whole range.  You need that for connected registers, stable tonal quality, good vocal closure and endurance.

With regard to your performance vocal range, you pick that for which you can deliver results and performance satisfactory for you and listeners.  Whether or not you make falsetto an integral part of that is an artistic choice.  However, there is little point in picking a high voice type and avoiding falsetto when the range becomes strained: crooning is neither healthy in the long run nor overly convincing.

Basically you should stick with the most comfortable modes of vocal production as your building blocks and work on connecting those across your total range in a controlled manner.

Answer (score 0):

Sit in front of a piano or a keyboard, play each note starting from bass, sing along with the note using aa or mmm sound, If you find difficulty in humming/singing any particular note, stop there and find the range.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you rejoice that you have such a large range, and can therefore sing such a wide variety of music!   If you're aiming for a classical career it should become apparent in which range(s) you can fully 'deliver the goods'.  In commercial music perhaps you can create your own style, exploiting  the full range, falsetto and all.